# Linking my game forum to my game

Tags: unity

I am thinking of adding a special achievement in my game where if the player reaches a certain score in my game forum ( my forum is kind of like SE where you get score instead of rep when answering questions ) he then gets a reward in the game. I just want to know if it is even possible to do such thing as I want more players to participate in the forum.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible. In order to do that you would have to give your game the ability to somehow identify what forum account belongs to the player.

You could do that by having the player enter their username and password in the game options. Doing that just to get the achievement would be a bit bothersome, though. But you could justify this if your game actually offers an in-game UI for viewing your forum (which is another good way to drive more traffic to it, by the way).

Another option which would be more user-friendly would be to check if any of the web browsers the user has installed has a login cookie stored for your forum. But note that a game looking at the user's browser history is quite suspicious behavior.

After you identified the user's account, your game could then use a webservice provided by your forum to check if that forum account exists, if the password matches and if the forum account has the required post score.

Implementation details for all this depend on what forum software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible trough a [webrequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). You sent a request to your web server to update the database. All you actually do is run a server side script, such as PHP, you feed it some additional post data and of course you need to verify everything that is being posted along with the request.